# Update cells of a master Excel file, if identifiers match other Excel files in folder

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to update my master Excel document with data of other Excel files  in the same folder as my master. The first row (heading) of each Excel file is identical.

Each element (row) has a unique identifier, the cell value of column 1, 3 and 6 combined.
The other columns of the row are the characteristics of that element.
I would like to update every element (row) of my master document.

If that unique element is found in any row of another Excel file in that folder, I would like to compare the cell values of each characteristic and update my master document with the information in the other file but not in my master.

The info in each cell is separated by a comma.
e.g. if characteristic 1 = shape, then the info in the cell would resemble "round, dent in a part, ..., ..".

If a row in any other file of my folder has a unique identifier that is not yet in my master, I want to copy that entire row beneath the last used row of my master document.

When I run this, nothing happens. (I don't know VBA. I tried multiple ChatGPT style tools to paste together something):

```vb
Sub UpdateMasterDocument()

    Dim MasterWb As Workbook
    Dim MasterWs As Worksheet
    Dim OtherWb As Workbook
    Dim OtherWs As Worksheet
    Dim MasterRow As Long
    Dim OtherRow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim MatchFound As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim MasterValue As String
    Dim OtherValue As String
    Dim MasterArray() As String
    Dim OtherArray() As String

    Set MasterWb = ThisWorkbook
    Set MasterWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    FolderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path

    FileName = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xls*")

    Do While FileName <> ""
        Set OtherWb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)
        Set OtherWs = OtherWb.Sheets(1)

        For MasterRow = 2 To MasterWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            MatchFound = False

            For OtherRow = 2 To OtherWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                If MasterWs.Cells(MasterRow, 1).Value & MasterWs.Cells(MasterRow, 3).Value & MasterWs.Cells(MasterRow, 6).Value = OtherWs.Cells(OtherRow, 1).Value & OtherWs.Cells(OtherRow, 3).Value & OtherWs.Cells(OtherRow, 6).Value Then
                    MatchFound = True

                    For i = 1 To OtherWs.Cells(OtherRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                        If i <> 1 And i <> 3 And i <> 6 Then
                            MasterValue = MasterWs.Cells(MasterRow, i).Value
                            OtherValue = OtherWs.Cells(OtherRow, i).Value
                            MasterArray = Split(MasterValue, ", ")
                            OtherArray = Split(OtherValue, ", ")

                            For j = LBound(OtherArray) To UBound(OtherArray)
                                If IsInArray(OtherArray(j), MasterArray) = False Then
                                    MasterWs.Cells(MasterRow, i).Value = MasterWs.Cells(MasterRow, i).Value & ", " & OtherArray(j)
                                End If
                            Next j
                        End If
                    Next i

                    Exit For
                End If
            Next OtherRow

            If MatchFound = False Then
                LastRow = MasterWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                OtherWs.Rows(OtherRow).Copy Destination:=MasterWs.Rows(LastRow)
            End If
        Next MasterRow

        OtherWb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        FileName = Dir
    Loop

End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i) = stringToBeFound Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    IsInArray = False
End Function
```

I tried to dumb it down to smaller pieces. The code below updated parts of cells for row in the same worksheet. I can't figure out how to implement this in the code above.

```vb
Sub UpdateData()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim rowZ As Range, rowX As Range
    Dim cellZ As Range, cellX As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set rng = ws.UsedRange

    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        Set rowZ = rng.Rows(i)
        For j = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
            If i <> j Then
                Set rowX = rng.Rows(j)
                If rowZ.Cells(1, 1).Value = rowX.Cells(1, 1).Value Then
                    For Each cellZ In rowZ.Cells
                        Set cellX = rowX.Cells(1, cellZ.Column)
                        If cellZ.Value <> cellX.Value Then
                            cellZ.Value = cellZ.Value & ";" & cellX.Value
                            cellX.Value = cellZ.Value
                        End If
                    Next cellZ
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What is `MyFolder`? isn't it `FolderPath`

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Indeed, I forgot to change Myfolder to Folderpath.
afterwards it gave an error message that it couldn't locate the folder. Only problem was the instead of looking for the "folder" it looked for "folderbook1.xlsx"

therefore I tried changing the next line too.

 Set MasterWb = ThisWorkbook
    Set MasterWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    FolderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path

    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "\*.xls*")

    Do While FileName <> ""
        Set OtherWb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & "\" & FileName)

Comment: When I run the code with these changes I just have a grey screen in my developer window as well as in my excel document.

Comment: Check the VBAProject names in Project window for open workbooks. Is there the workbook where the code is?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Dictionary Object to match the unique identifier and scan the other excel files just once.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateMasterDocument()

    Const SEP = ";"
    Dim wbMaster As Workbook, wb As Workbook
    Dim wsMaster As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim Folder As String, filename As String
    Dim sMaster As String, sSrc As String, v
    
    Dim r As Long, rMaster As Long
    Dim rLastMaster As Long, rLastSrc As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long
   
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, m As Long, f As Long
    Dim t0: t0 = Timer
    
    Dim dict As Object, k, ar
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' master unique ids
    Set wbMaster = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsMaster = wbMaster.Sheets(1)
    With wsMaster
        rLastMaster = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ar = .Range("A1:F1").Resize(rLastMaster)
        For r = 2 To UBound(ar)
            k = ar(r, 1) & SEP & ar(r, 3) & SEP & ar(r, 6)
            If dict.exists(k) Then
                MsgBox "Duplicate ID " & k, vbCritical, "Row " & r
                Exit Sub
            Else
                dict.Add k, r
            End If
        Next
    End With
    
    ' scan folder
    Folder = wbMaster.Path
    filename = Dir(Folder & "\*.xls")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While filename <> ""
        f = f + 1
        'Debug.Print filename
        
        'scan rows in file
        Set ws = Workbooks.Open(Folder & filename).Sheets(1)
        With ws
            rLastSrc = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            ar = .Range("A1:F1").Resize(rLastSrc)
            For r = 2 To UBound(ar)
                lastCol = .Cells(r, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                k = ar(r, 1) & SEP & ar(r, 3) & SEP & ar(r, 6)
                
                ' exists in master ?
                If dict.exists(k) Then
                    rMaster = dict(k)
                    For i = 1 To lastCol
                       sMaster = wsMaster.Cells(rMaster, i)
                       sSrc = .Cells(r, i)
                       For Each v In Split(sSrc, ",")
                          'Debug.Print "'" & sMaster & "'", "'" & Trim(v) & "'"
                          If InStr(1, sMaster, Trim(v), 1) = 0 Then
                             sMaster = sMaster & ", " & v
                             m = m + 1
                             wsMaster.Cells(rMaster, i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 127)
                          End If
                       Next
                       wsMaster.Cells(rMaster, i) = sMaster
                    Next
                Else
                    ' add new row to master
                    rLastMaster = rLastMaster + 1
                    ws.Cells(r, 1).Resize(, lastCol).Copy wsMaster.Cells(rLastMaster, 1)
                    n = n + 1
                End If
            Next
        End With
        filename = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' result
    MsgBox f & " files scanned in " & Folder & vbLf & _
           m & " cells updated" & vbLf & _
           n & " rows added", vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")

End Sub
```

Comment: You're only going for xls documents? Also, maybe a skip is necessary in case the file you're trying to open is the masterfile? (not sure here)